# How to parse quotation marks and comma in c++

Tags: c++, scanf, quotation-marks

I have a huge file to parse. Previously, it was separated by either `space` or `comma` and I used `sscanf(string, "%lf %lf ", &aa, &bb);` to get the data into my program.

But now the data format is changed to `"122635.670399999","209705.752799999"`, with both comma and quotation marks. And I have no idea how to deal with it.

Actually, my previous code was found online and I had a really hard time finding proper documentation for this kind of problem. It will be great if you can recommend some to me.

Comment: Does it consist of lines of data? If so, why not read in a line and then parse the line at the commas, then remove the quotes?

Comment: Yes, the data are in lines. Could you explain to me how to remove the quotes?

Comment: [std::regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) Also google for "how to parse CSV", you should find enough info even on SO.

Comment: Do you need to verify that the file includes the quotes and commas, or do you just want to read the numbers, regardless of whether the commas and/or quotes are present?

Comment: I only need to read the numbers, and I think the overall format is uniform (exactly the same as I listed for each line, just millions of them).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than read a string, then remove the commas and quotes from the strings, and finally convert the data to numbers, I'd probably create a locale object that classifies commas and quotes as white space, imbue the stream with that locale, and read the numbers without further adieu.

```
// here's our ctype facet:
class my_ctype : public std::ctype<char> {
public:
    mask const *get_table() { 
        static std::vector<std::ctype<char>::mask> 
            table(classic_table(), classic_table()+table_size);

        // tell it to classify quotes and commas as "space":
        table['"'] = (mask)space;
        table[','] = (mask)space;
        return &table[0];
    }
    my_ctype(size_t refs=0) : std::ctype<char>(get_table(), false, refs) { }
};
```

Using that, we can read the data something like this:

```
int main() { 
    // Test input from question:
    std::string input("\"122635.670399999\",\"209705.752799999\"");

    // Open the "file" of the input (from the string, for test purposes).
    std::istringstream infile(input);

    // Tell the stream to use the locale we defined above:
    infile.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new my_ctype));

    // Read the numbers into a vector of doubles:
    std:vector<double> numbers{std::istream_iterator<double>(infile),
                               std::istream_iterator<double>()};

    // Print out the sum of the numbers to show we read them:
    std::cout << std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0.0);
}
```

Note that once we've imbued the stream with a locale using our ctype facet, we can just read numbers as if the commas and quotes didn't exist at all. Since the ctype facet classifies them as white-space, they're completely ignored beyond acting as separators between other stuff.

I'm pointing this out primarily to make clear that there's no magic in any of the processing after that. There's nothing special about using `istream_iterator` instead of (for example) `double value; infile >> value;` if you prefer to do that. You can read the numbers any of the ways you'd normally read numbers that were separated by white space -- because as far as the stream cares, that's *exactly* what you have.

Comment: It works! In addition to solving my problem, you reply also introduced me a lot of new stuff. btw, should you change `s.imbue`  to `infile.imbue` in your code?

Comment: @KuN: Oops -- yes, I should. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you have got comma separated data in strings then just remove `"` from string like :
let say string is str1

```
str1.erase(std::remove(str1.begin(), str1.end(), '"'), str1.end());
```

this will erase all occurrences of `"`

```
    //Use below code to convert string into float
    float f1;    
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<str1;
    ss>>f1;
```

Comment: You do that this way also , or if you get data like `"122635.670399999"` in a strings then remove `"` and convert that string into float.both ways solves your problem.

Comment: thanks, but in my application, `&aa, &bb` are two different variables. Now all of them would be imported to `aa` I am still reading description of `stringstream`.